# Button click inside autocomplete

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, autocomplete

I was working on autocomplete with button inside each li element. I dont want to call select event of autocomplete when this button is clicked. But select event is being called , is there any workaround fo this.

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/LCv8L/348/)

```
.data("autocomplete")._renderItem = function( ul, item ) {
    var li= $("<li></li>")
            .data("item.autocomplete", item)
            .append("<a style='text-align:left' href='google.com'>    <span>"+item.label+"</span><input class='prod-list-addbtn' value='ADD' type='button' style='position: relative;top: 6px;'></a>")
.appendTo(ul);
    return li;
}

 $(document).delegate('ul .prod-list-addbtn', 'click', function (e) {
                  e.stopPropagation();
                  e.preventDefault();
     alert('dont call select of autocomplete, but still called');
                  return false;
   });
```

Comment: so U don't want to call delegate event bind for button click right ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<li class="ui-menu-item" role="menuitem"><a style="text-align:left" href="google.com" class="ui-corner-all" tabindex="-1">    <span>Tommy Smith</span></a><input class="prod-list-addbtn" value="ADD" type="button" style="position: relative;top: 6px;z-index: 400;"></li>
```

You can put input element into li element not the a element.
By this way you do not trigger select event

--- CHANGE HERE LIKE BELOW-----

```
var li= $("<li></li>")
            .data("item.autocomplete", item)
    .append("<a style='text-align:left;float:left' href='google.com'>    <span>"+item.label+"</span></a><input class='prod-list-addbtn' value='ADD' type='button' style='position: relative;top: 6px;float:left'>")
.appendTo(ul);
```